# Can we create new combo boxes after user clicks something from another combo box in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox, pyqt6

I am working on a ui project that requires me to change a lot of things based on what option user selects from the combo box. In this code i was trying to create another combo box if user selects 'b' but it isn't working
What am i doing wrong?

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(450, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()


    def UiComponents(self):

        items = ['a','b','c']
        x=20
        y=15
        self.create_combo(items,x,y)
        button = QPushButton("Click", self)
        button.pressed.connect(self.ffind)
        button.setGeometry(20,55,40,30)

    def ffind(self):
        connect = self.combo_box.currentText()
        if connect == "b":
            #print('you selected b')
            list1 = ['1','2','3']
            self.create_combo(list1, 200,15)
    def create_combo(self, items, x, y):
        #print("inside function")
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        self.combo_box.setGeometry(x, y, 150, 30)
        self.combo_box.addItems(items)

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

P.S: this is my first question on stackoverflow so forgive me if i missed something :/

I tried to create a function to create combo boxes everytime its called. It works just fine if i call it normally but I want to create that only if user selects the appropriate option from the first combo box.
I tried to call it inside a function which verifies whether the option selected by the user is the one i need (in this code its 'b') but it does nothing whatsoever.

Comment: `self.combo_box.show()`. Besides, if it's just one combo that gets created, you should consider to create it since the beginning and just hide/disable it and then show/enable when necessary. Note that you are overwriting `self.combo_box`, which means that the next time the button is pressed, the function won't work as expected, because it will use the new combo instead of the previous one; be more careful with object naming and always use intuitive and verbose names. Finally, you should always avoid explicit geometries, and use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.

Comment: @musicamante OMG thank you , i added self.combo_box.show() and it finally worked. I thought something was wrong with the logic itself. And I will definitely check out layout managers as i proceed with the project. Also, how will i be able to enable/disable combo boxes?

Comment: All widgets support the [`enable`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop) property: `setEnabled()` will enable or disable the widget depending on the argument. I strongly suggest you to read the whole page of the [QWidget documentation](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html), since it's the base class for *all* Qt widgets. About the layouts, consider that 99% of the times avoiding them is just a terrible idea that sooner or later everybody regrets; note that once you add widgets to layouts, it's not necessary to explicitly show them, as they will be automatically shown with their parent.